# windows phone browser in desktop mode

Tags: browser, windows-phone

How can force a windows phone to use the desktop view mode in the mobile borwser?

In the settings it is possible to set the browser to use the desktop view becasue some featers seem to be missing in the mobile view causing my site not beeing displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make websites display in desktop mode in the `WebBrowser` control, you must change its user agent. You can do so using this:

```
webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com", null, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)");
```

That code changes the WebBrowser's user agent to that of desktop Internet Explorer 10.

However, it will only change the User Agent for the page navigated to. When users click links, the user agent will be changed back. To fix this, set the WebBrowser's Navigating event to this:

```
private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
        string url = e.Uri.ToString();
        if (!url.Contains("#changedua"))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            url = url + "#changedua";
            webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(url), null, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)");
        }
}
```

In this code, we check to see if the url contains a flag, "#changedua". If it does, we allow the navigation. If it does not, we cancel the navigation. Then, we navigate again using our custom user agent, and adding the flag to show that it is valid.

Comment: hi, is this solution only when running in an app or can I configure the webserver to, to send this Header so the mobile web browser is set to IE10 Desktop mode?